# Create stored procedure results in an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I am trying to create a stored procedure but each time I try to save it I get an error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure forum_Insert_Post, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '@description'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure forum_Insert_Post, Line 9
Must declare the scalar variable "@title"
```

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE forum_Insert_Post
     @title nvarchar
     @description nvarchar
     @subcategoryId int
     @date dateTime
     @usernameId uniqueidentifier
AS
    INSERT INTO forum_posts (PostTitle , PostContent , PostDate , UserId , SubcategoryId)
    VALUES (@title , @description , @date , @usernameId , @subcategoryId)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need commas after the parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE forum_Insert_Post
 @title nvarchar,
 @description nvarchar,
 @subcategoryId int,
 @date dateTime,
 @usernameId uniqueidentifier
AS
INSERT INTO forum_posts (PostTitle , PostContent , 
 PostDate , UserId , SubcategoryId)
VALUES (@title , @description , @date , @usernameId , @subcategoryId)
```

Comment: dam I must be blind as a bat can't believe I did not see that thanks

Comment: As StuartLC says, you almost certainly want to add a size too, since `nvarchar` without a size defaults to `nvarchar(1)` (except for `CAST` and `CONVERT`)

Comment: Yeah, you're right adding a size would be beneficial as the code probably won't work the way you expect it to without it.

Answer (score 4):

Just add some commas, and also give the `nvarchar`s an appropriate size, else it will truncate to 1 char :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE forum_Insert_Post
     @title nvarchar(20),
     @description nvarchar(20),
     @subcategoryId int,
     @date dateTime,
     @usernameId uniqueidentifier
AS
    INSERT INTO forum_posts (PostTitle , PostContent , PostDate , UserId , SubcategoryId)
    VALUES (@title , @description , @date , @usernameId , @subcategoryId)
```

SQLFiddle of the `NVARCHAR` truncation [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be560/1)